# How to skip end of line comments with Astropy ascii table reader?

Tags: astropy

I want to read an ascii file that contains end-of line comments into an Astropy table. Something like this:

```
a | b
1 | 2
3 | 4 # this is a comment
# another comment
5 | 6
```

As shown [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/cdeil/55c1b80e50a187692b3d), this doesn't do what I want:

```
Table.read(filename, format='ascii.csv', delimiter='|', comment='\s*#')
```

What options do I have to pass to `Table.read` to make this work?

Comment: Worse comes to worse, you can also pass an in-memory string in to the ascii reader, so you could do your own preprocessing first if the file isn't overly large.  Otherwise your own CSV reader is a good bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, but it should take only a few lines of custom code.  The basic idea is to make a subclass of the [CSV reader](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/stable/astropy/io/ascii/basic.py#L222) where you override the `data_class = CsvData` with your own Data class which itself is a subclass of `CsvData`.  In your Data subclass override the `process_lines` method to do your custom comment line handling. Look at the `BaseData` class in `core.py` to see the baseline `process_lines` behavior.

```
from astropy.io.ascii.basic import Csv, CsvData

class CsvCommentData(CsvData):
    comment = '#'  # regular expression not allowed for this reader

    def _strip_trailing_comments(self, lines):
        for line in lines:
            index = line.rfind(self.comment)
            if index >= 0:
                line = line[:index]
            yield line

    def process_lines(self, lines):
        return super(CsvCommentData, self).process_lines(self._strip_trailing_comments(lines))

class CsvComment(Csv):
    _format_name = 'csv_comment'
    _io_registry_can_write = True
    _description = 'Comma-separated-values with trailing comments allowed'

    data_class = CsvCommentData
```

Comment: Thanks Tom ... that's very complicated though ... I'll just use pandas for the parsing and then convert to Astropy Table.